# Toggle Button Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, toggle

I wanted to know how do I keep a toggle button in the on(true) position after I close the userform and re-open

Nothing. thatsway I need your help to sew if i can set my userform as i think before. May an wise mab help me on this issue please

Comment: No idea what the second paragraph is on about.  As @Domenic posted - just set it to TRUE when the form initialises, but I've a feeling you want it to re-open in the same state as when you closed it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UserForm_Initialize event to set the togglebutton to True.  Accordingly, place the following code in the userform code module...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ToggleButton1.Value = True
    
End Sub
```

Change the name of the togglebutton accordingly.